# How to get modal dialog to send correct object in pug iteration?

Tags: foreach, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, pug

In my pug file I have this chunk of code

```
each doc, i in docs
      li.list-group-item
        a.btn.btn-default(href='/docs/edit/'+doc._id)=doc.docname
        b &nbsp;
        button.btn.btn-primary.pull-right(type='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#login-modal') Share
        #login-modal.modal(role='dialog')
            .modal-dialog
                .modal-content
                    .modal-header
                        h2 Invite users
                        button.close(type='button' data-dismiss='modal') &times;
                    .modal-body
                        form(name='form' onsubmit='put();' method='POST', action='/docs/share/'+doc._id)
                            #form-group
                                label Who would you like to share it with? (Username)
                                input.form-control(name='userfriend' type='text')
                            input.btn.btn-primary(type='submit' value='Submit')
                    .modal-footer
                        button.btn.btn-primary(type='button' data-dismiss='modal') Close
```

The problem is that although the share button does take me to docs/share/:id the id is always that of the first document in the list. This is strange because I use the doc._id property for another button and that one works. Is there something special about the modal button that doesn't allow you to use ids other than the first entry?

To be more clear, lets say there are two entries in my docs: A and B. Their ids are respectively a and b. The share button of A AND the share button of B sends a query to docs/share/a , when the share button of B should send a query to docs/share/b. Even when there are more documents, the share button always sends it to the first in the list. After deleting the first in the list, it will then send a query to the new first in the list. Any ideas on how to fix this? For background I am using NodeJS and Mongoose in coordination with this but I don't think that's necessary as other webpages work fine with the doc._id property, its only the modal button that seems to have trouble with only doc._id of the first doc in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with multiple modals on the page with the same id.  This line is inside your each loop:

```
#login-modal.modal(role='dialog')
```

There's nothing unique about that id, so when you call your modal by id it will just use the first one it finds.  You may have generated twenty modals on your page, but they all have the id `login-modal`.

Change that line to include the doc id and then make sure you add it to your modal call as well, wherever that code sits.

```
.modal(id= ('login-modal-' + doc._id) role='dialog')
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I also needed to add ```'login-modal-'+doc._id``` in the data-target

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "make sure you add it to your modal call as well, wherever that code sits"